# Jquery problem with appending and binding in the same time

Tags: jquery, function, select, popup, bind

I'm working on a fine rolldown select solution for my website.
I made an `<a name="iwanthereanid" class="popper">Click Here!</a>` link.
By clicking on it I call a `popup()` function.

```
$(".popper").click(function() {
    popup($(this));
});
```

In the `popup()` function i check was this already opened? No?
Lets make a div and fill it with things by `fillwiththings()`.

```
function popup(where) 
{
    if (where.hasClass("on")) 
    {
        where.removeClass("on");
        where.next("div").remove();
    }
    else 
    {
        where.addClass("on");
        fillwiththings(where);
    }
}

function selectclose(where)
{
    var nameval = $(this).attr("name");
    var textval = $(this).text();
    where.attr("name", nameval);
    where.text(textval);
    where.removeClass("on");
    where.next("div").remove();
}

function fillwiththings(where, id)
{
    $container = $('<div class="popup"></div>')
    for (i = 0; i < object.length; i++)
    {
        $container.append($('<a name="'+jsonobject[i]["id"]+'">'+jsonobject[i]["name"]+'</a>').bind("click", {where: where}, selectclose()));
    }
}
```

In `fillwiththings()` I'd like to bind to the appended `<a></a>` an another function with the where parameter, to close, and replace the a(Click Here!) tag's text and name value. But the bind fails. What did i missed? Please help in this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not accessing the `where` parameter correctly. The event data is not passed as parameter to the event handler, it is a property of the event object:

```
function selectclose(event) {
    event.data.where
        .attr("name", $(this).attr("name"))
        .text($(this).text())
        .removeClass("on")
        .next("div").remove();
}
```

The other problem is that you pass the **return value** of `selectclose()` to bind. You have to pass the function directly:

```
$container.append($(...).bind("click", {where: where}, selectclose));
//                                          no parenthesis ------^
```