# Dynamically build dropdown list using Jquery opens and closes immediately

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu

My dynamically built dropdown list opens and closes immediately, I've got no chance of selecting any option, here is how the code of the function that builds the list looks like:

```
            function MoveItem(itemID) {                
                var selector = "#mov" + itemID;
                var replaceValue = "<select class=ddl id=select" + itemID + ">" + $("input:text").map(function() { return '<option>' + $(this).val() || null; }).get().join("</option>");
                replaceValue += "</select>";                   
                $(selector).html(replaceValue);
            }
```

Any idea why is it so ? Thks guys.

Answer (score 0):

Bind it to change event. Like `$("#yourid").bind("change", MoveItem(this));` I think it will do it. :)

Comment: thks for getting back, I can see what you're trying to do but where does that code exactly go ? Still trying to get my head around Jquery stuff. MoveItem(itemID) function is inside the last cell of every table row at the moment.

Comment: I think I know where it goes except that my table rows are built dynamically so I might have to hook it up with .live as well ?

Comment: Aye. Or how about to bind each selects after you append them? Like in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434719/jquery-problem-with-appending-and-binding-in-the-same-time

Comment: You can see in the end of the problem. `$container.append($('<a name="'+jsonobject[i]["id"]+'">'+jsonobject[i]["name"]+'</a>').bind("click", {where: where}, selectclose()));`